# Create hyperlink from class library in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a hyperlink from a class library project but I'm getting empty result.

Code:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
var url = urlHelper.Action("View", "Collection", new { area = "Administration", id = Request.Id });
```

Is there a way to create a hyperlink from a class library project? If so, how?

**Edit**:

`urlHelper` is an object of `UrlHelper` class from `System.Web.Mvc`
urlHelper is returning empty string.

Comment: What's the exact behaviour you're seeing? Is `url` `null` or `string.Empty`? Or something else?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Too much guesswork involved if anyone tries to help. What is "View"? What do you mean by "hyperlink from class library"? Do you have controllers and views in the library? Where are the routes for those defined? Etc.

Comment: Edited, please check!

Comment: @SVI, comment on the answers to your question, if they do not answer your question. How do you expect people to be able to help you when you don't communicate?

Answer (score 1):

One of the way I handle that kind of problem is to use dependency injection and pass to your class in the library a service interface (ex : IHyperlinkFormatter) that will provide methods to generate urls. This interface could then be implemented by a class in your MVC project that knows about the available routes. By doing that, you also have better control on your unit tests and you improve your code quality by respecting the Single Responsibility SOLID principle.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is inside a controller, you don't need to create an instance of the `UrlHelper` class. The Controller class has a Url property of type `UlrHelper` ([See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.url(v=vs.118).aspx)).

In your controller, you'll have:

```
var url = Url.Action("View", "Collection", new { area = "Administration", id = Request.Id });
```

Answer (score 0):

`UrlHelper` you create does not know anything about routes which exists in your web app. You can pass `UrlHelper` of controller as parameter.

You can use also

```
new UrlHelper(requestContext, routeCollection)
```

This way controller initialize property `Url` of `UrlHelper` type

Comment: Thank you. Updated. Also route collection is required.